# Can get variable from secondary table in api on a list page, but not on single item page

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

This page reading and displaying a full table from an API works perfectly;

```
<template>
    <b-col>
        <h2>    
            Enrolments
            <b-button :to="{ name: 'createEnrolment', params: { id: this.$route.params}}" variant="warning" class="float-right">Create</b-button>
        </h2>

        <b-card
            v-for="enrolment in enrolments"
            :key="enrolment._id"
        >
            <p>Course id:{{ enrolment.course.id }}</p>
            <p>Course title:{{ enrolment.course.title }}</p>    
            <p>Status:{{ enrolment.status }}</p>
            <p>Created:{{ enrolment.created_at }}</p>
            <p>Date:{{ enrolment.date }}</p>
            <p>Lecturer:{{ enrolment.lecturer.name }}</p>
            <p>Lecturer email:{{ enrolment.lecturer.email }}</p>
            <p>Updated:{{ enrolment.updated_at }}</p>
            <p>Time:{{ enrolment.time }}</p>
            <b-button :to="{ name: 'viewEnrolment', params: { id: enrolment.id}}" variant="warning">View</b-button>
        </b-card>
    </b-col>
</template>

<script>
import axios from '@/config'

export default {
    name: "viewEnrolments",
    components: {},    
    data(){
        return {
            enrolments: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData()
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token')

            axios
            .get(`/enrolments`, 
            {
                headers: {
                    "Accepted": `application/json`, 
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })          
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                this.enrolments = response.data.data
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

However, when I try to view just one entry to the enrolments table, it cannot recognise or get that data from the courses table, giving the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')", which comes from line 8: `<p>Course id:{{ enrolment.course.id }}</p>`

```
<template>
    <b-col>
        <h2>    
            Enrolments
        </h2>

        <b-card>
            <p>Course id:{{ enrolment.course.id }}</p>
            <p>Course title:{{ enrolment.course.title }}</p>    
            <p>Status:{{ enrolment.status }}</p>
            <p>Created:{{ enrolment.created_at }}</p>
            <p>Date:{{ enrolment.date }}</p>
            <p>Lecturer:{{ enrolment.lecturer.name }}</p>
            <p>Lecturer email:{{ enrolment.lecturer.email }}</p>
            <p>Updated:{{ enrolment.updated_at }}</p>
            <p>Time:{{ enrolment.time }}</p>
        </b-card>
    </b-col>
</template>

<script>
import axios from '@/config'

export default {
    name: "viewEnrolment",
    components: {},    
    data(){
        return {
            enrolment: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData()
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            
            axios
            .get(`/enrolments/${this.$route.params.id}`, 
            {
                headers: {
                    "Accepted": `application/json`, 
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })          
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                this.enrolments = response.data.data
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried a few different ways to link the courses table to the enrolment one, but nothing worked. But I don't even understand what I have in the first one that allows me to reference the courses table, but not in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have misspelled your variable in the second component, `viewEnrolment`. You have the plural **enrollments**:

```js
  this.enrolments = response.data.data
```

But in your component HTML, you're using the singular **enrollment**:

```html
<p>Course id:{{ enrolment.course.id }}</p>
```

Also, this is just an additional tidbit: In Vue components, I would typically try to call API's in the `created()` [hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#created), not the `mounted()` hook. `created()` comes before, and is called when data observation is set up, but **before** the component is **actually mounted to HTML**.

This could prevent weird issues where when trying to use `this.enrolment` in your HTML, it's not actually being available yet, because the API request isn't finished.

Comment: That was it, a silly mistake, thank you.